# Neti pot on Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, medicine, yom-kippur

Can one use a neti pot on Yom Kippur?
It is an ayurvedic technique for clearing the sinuses, basically pouring warm salt water through one nostril and out the other.

It doesn't go into your mouth.  But it might go in your throat a bit. It clears the nose to breathe.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47951

Comment: See the related question from msh210. (I asked that question, BTW :-) I know that the Neti pot is made by the same company that makes the squeeze bottle. But I don't recall the mechanism for how it works. Also, I assume that in your case, no Shabbat violations are performed in making the water "warm" (i.e., you are not cooking on Yom Kippur). You may want to edit in that part, so we are clear on that aspect. Beyond that, if the mechanism is the same, then, I think you have your answer, already. Let us know.

Comment: Thanks DanF. One difference is that there is no squeezing here, only pouring. The pot is ceramic with a spout and you tip your head at an angle to have the water come in and out. Shabbos and Yom Kippur are two different questions. I don't see why this would be prohibited on Shabbos, provided, as you say, the water is heated in a kumkum or some such thing. Perhaps I'm wrong and refuah is more broad, but I thought it applied mostly to medication.

Comment: Clearly you can blow your nose, and even pick your nose, on Shabbos, and you can also wash your face, gargle mouthwash, etc.  Not sure about earwax. But on Yom Kippur some of these drop out..

Comment: It looks like the only concerns are Shabbat-related which would apply to Yom Kippur. You are not eating or drinking anything. I think the minor concern of salt water going down your throat seems less than a mouthful, is non-intentional, and is not done for the pleasure of drinking. Whether this is considered *refu'ah* is the debate, and see the answer given in my other question coming from dinonline.org who claims it's OK. I'm not sure why it's NOT considered *refu'ah* according to them, as they didn't explain that. But, I'm implicitly trusting their decision coming from a pool of rabbanim.

Comment: @DanF re: "I think the minor concern of salt water going down your throat seems less than a mouthful, is non-intentional, and is not done for the pleasure of drinking"  this came to my mail today as part of the day's halachot, "It is forbidden to rinse one's mouth with water or other liquids (e.g. mouth wash) because of the possibility of swallowing some liquid.
(סעיף א ו־ד וס"ק א, ט ו־יא; ביאורים ומוספים דרשו, 3 ו־22)" So even when the fear is any liquid might be unintebtionally swallowed, this source says "no."